# R - How to get at a string from a single column and row in a data frame

Tags: r

So I'm trying to do [these problems](http://rosalind.info/problems/as-table/) in R in order to learn it.

But I'm stuck on [the first problem](http://rosalind.info/problems/dna/) to simply count the frequency of charactors in a string.  I can't even seem to get past loading the data and getting to the string :-(

How do I do something like print the first charactor of the string from this text file?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
> rosalind_dna <- read.table("~/Downloads/rosalind_dna.txt", quote="")
Warning message:
In read.table("~/Downloads/rosalind_dna.txt", quote = "") :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on '~/Downloads/rosalind_dna.txt'
>   viewData(rosalind_dna)
> str(rosalind_dna[1,1,1])
 Factor w/ 1 level "GGCCCGGTTACTGCGACTGAACAATCAAAATCTGAAGCATTTAAGCCAAACCAATTGAGATCGACTTACGAGCGATAACCCAGTATATTCAAGTGCTACTGATGAGGCGTGGTCCCCTGGACAAGGC"| __truncated__: 1
```

Comment: Your urls are making server errors! Do you want only to display the first character from the whole file or the first character of any line?

Comment: I think that site is down.  Hopefully it will be back up soon.

Comment: Ultimately I want to loop through the charactors in the file and get the frequency.  I'm confused how I get to the point of having a string instead of a data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done so far is just fine.

`read.table` returns a data frame. In this case, you just get a data frame with a single column and only a single value in that column.

By default, R will convert character columns in data frames to factors. You can convert it back using `as.character`.

Then you'll simply want to split that single string into individual characters (`strsplit`) and then make a table (`table`). (No need for loops!)

Here's a toy example illustrating all the functions I mentioned:

```
> dat <- data.frame(V1 = factor("abcdfjtusje"))
> str(dat)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 1 level "abcdfjtusje": 1
> x <- as.character(dat[1,1])
> x
[1] "abcdfjtusje"
> strsplit(x,"")
[[1]]
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "f" "j" "t" "u" "s" "j" "e"

> strsplit(x,"")[[1]]
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "f" "j" "t" "u" "s" "j" "e"
> table(strsplit(x,"")[[1]])

a b c d e f j s t u 
1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 
>
```

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Good point, thanks. In my defense, I was trying to be explicit to an R newcomer about the fact that `strsplit` will return a list, which can trip people up at times.

Comment: Wow, it's so easy.  I guess I shouldn't be thinking so procedurally in R.  I don't understand what the [[1]] is for though.  Doesn't table need to operate on the whole list?

Comment: @Greg As Sven pointed out, `table(strsplit(x,""))` would have worked just fine in this case. I was trying to be explicit about the fact that `strsplit` is vectorized: `strsplit(c("abc","def"),"")` returns a list of length 2. In our simplified case, we have a list of length one, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: It is even simpler if `scan` is used insead of `read.table`: `table(strsplit(scan(file = "~/Downloads/rosalind_dna.txt", what = character()), ""))`

Answer (score 2):

I've copied the file in the link into `/tmp/string.txt` This file has just has a single line of:

```
AGCTTTTCATTCTGACTGCAACGGGCAATATGTCTCTGTGTGGATTAAAAAAAGAGTGTCTGATAGCAGC
```

We can read the file using the `readLines` command:

```
s = readLines("/tmp/string.txt")
```

The variable `s` is just a single string. To split up the bases, we use:

```
strsplit(s, "")
```

then tabulate using `table`:

```
table(strsplit(s, ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the first character of the whole file you may act as follows:

```
s = readLines("Your file.txt",n=1)
substr(s, 1, 1)
```

To display the first character of every line:

```
s = readLines("Your file.txt")
substr(s, 1, 1)
```

To display n-th character of every line:

```
n = 5
s = readLines("Your file.txt")
substr(s, n, n)
```

Comment: When you are trying to read the first character, you are not thinking your file to be a table, so this is more convenient approach

Comment: @Greg There is nothing wrong with the approach you were taking. You just needed a 1-2 more steps, that's all.

Comment: It's a matter of taste. Some people prefer `<-` for assignment. I wondered if you used the other direction because you are used to writing from right to left.

Comment: @Roland No it does not depend on right to left righting, in some cases when I remember to assign the value of a function to a variable after I have written all the arguments, I use this direction :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use readLine and substr command to solve the problem, but if you insist to grep the first character from a datafram, simply, you can use
`substr(dataframe$colname,1,1)`
it will return a string vector.